# How to retrieve referrer tag, and save in custom fields for each WC order?

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, ref

I need to save the traffic source of each order for my Woocommerce store because I need to know what internal page or external website had resulted in that order. I'll need this for customer service needs.

I can add tags to links pointing to each product. I think that it should be possible to isolate those tags, and save them in a custom field for each order.

I'm not able to code, but I have a general understanding. Is there a plugin that does this? Or is there a code which I can add to the site's files which would achieve this goal?

I'm guessing that I should add to the "order-details.php" file, a code that looks like this:

```
<?php 
if ( wp_get_referer() )
{  $referer_field = wp_referer_field( $echo );
add_order_meta (Referrer, $referer_field);
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Rambod

Answer (score 0):

You can use update_post_meta for this once you have the ID.

It will look something like this:

```
if ( wp_get_referer() ){  
  $referer_field = wp_referer_field( $echo );
  update_post_meta (get_the_id(), $referer_field, 'referrer-here');
}
```

I hope this helps?

Comment: Hi Danyo. Thank you so much for your help! I tried your code, but I'm not seeing any results. Let me tell you exactly what I did, and tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

1.) I created an order-detail.php file in the child theme, and place your code in it like this: http://i.imgur.com/4KvqPmE.png

2.) I appended the reference I wanted to the end of the URL of the product page, and used it in a hyperlink sending the viewer to the product: http://i.imgur.com/NxuEcdc.png 

3.) I clicked on that link, and ordered a product. But nothing shows in the custom fields: http://i.imgur.com/1nPueRA.png